# Find the sum of the areas in the figure below

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

For reference: In the figure, calculate $S_x$, knowing that $DILO\space$ is a parallelogram and $S_1 + S_2 +S_3= 8m^2$ (Answer: $8m^2$)

[image]

My progress: I traced to the perpendicular $CH$ and marked the areas indicated below

Let: $S_a = S\triangle BGE\\
S_b=S\triangle LJO\\
S_c=S\triangle CEJ\\
h =LO=IO\\
S_2=\frac{BG.h}{2}\\
S_1+S_a = \frac{BG.CH}{2}\\
S_3+S_b =\frac{ HO.h}{2}\\
S_a+S_x+S_b = \frac{h.BO}{2}\\
S_c+S_x = \frac{CH.h}{2}$

I'm not able to relate the areas

Comment: $S_1+S_2+S_a=\frac12 AB\cdot BH$, $S_3+S_b=\frac12 LO\cdot OH$, $S_a+S_b+S_x=\frac12 LO \cdot BO$.

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu How do you get to the solution with these relationships?..I tried but I got to Sx = Sx

Comment: Let add first two equations from my comment: $S_1+S_2+S_3+S_a+S_b=$ $\frac12 AB\cdot BH+\frac12 LO\cdot OH$. Then use $AB=DI=LO$ and $BH+OH=BO$: $S_1+S_2+S_3+S_a+S_b=$ $\frac12 LO\cdot BH+\frac12 LO\cdot OH=$ $\frac12 LO\cdot(BH+OH)=$ $\frac12 LO\cdot BO$. Then use third equation from my comment: $S_1+S_2+S_3+S_a+S_b=S_a+S_b+S_x$. Then subtract $S_a+S_b$ from both parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $S_2=\frac{BG.h}{2}$ and also $S_2=\frac{AB.BG}{2}$, comparing the equations we get $AB=h$
Thus we have:-
$$S_3+S_b =\frac{ HO.h}{2}\\$$
$$S_a+S_x+S_b = \frac{h.BO}{2}\\$$
$$S_1+S_2+S_a=\frac{h⋅BH}{2}$$
Adding the First and Third Equations:-
$$S_3+S_b+S_1+S_2+S_a=\frac{ HO.h}{2}+\frac{h⋅BH}{2}$$
$$\rightarrow 8m^2 + S_a+S_b=\frac{(h).(HO+BH)}{2}$$
$$\rightarrow 8m^2 + \frac{h.BO}{2}-S_x=\frac{h.BO}{2}$$
This follows from the 2nd equation.
Thus we get $S_x=8m^2$ as required